# Подписанный апплет: отказ в доступе к порту

Tags: java, html, applet

Имеется подписанный апплет, который должен читать данные из порта. Апплет совершенно рабочий и подписанный как положено. Пытаюсь его стартовать из моего вот такого html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Applet-Test</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1> Hi html works </h1>
    <applet code="MyApplet.class" archive="myapplet.jar" width=320 height=320>
    <param name="locale" value="de"/>
    </applet>
</body>

</html>
```

Этот вариант работает теперь. А вот такой вопрос теперь [Настройки безопасности блокируют подписанный апплет запущеный через Javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510487/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-javascript)

Comment: При этом апплет уже нормально работает на сайте. Что я делаю неправильно в HTML? Может надо разрешения как-то включить?

Comment: А там что у вас com-порт открывается? Наверное запрет стоит на такие действия. А то ишь повадились по портам из интернета шарить. Потом деньги пропадают, компромат где-то всплывет. Хром так вообще уже наверное прекратил поддержку в том числе и апплетов.

Comment: @Sergey, да не.Подписанному апплету много чего можно. Просто не может получить свойство к системной проперти `purejavacomm.loglevel`

Comment: @Helena2977, поищите про файл `java.policy`. Вам нужно в нем запросить разрешение  `permission java.util.PropertyPermission "purejavacomm.loglevel", "read";`  Возможно в проекте даже где-то остался этот файл.

Comment: java.ppolicy есть только в Java. В проекте апплета нету такого. И я не понимаю, почему через сайт этот же апплет запускается с нужным разрешением, а у меня нет? Может все-таки что-то в HTML надо настроить? У меня соединение с прибором через USB. Драйвер для прибора установлен.

Comment: Да кстати, может это тоже важно, апплет запускается с сайта без всяких проблем, а когда я запускаю от себя, то Firefox ругается на небезопасность версии java и требует подтверждения для запуска. Я уже нашла, что это из-за java7, но ведь опять-таки с сайта без этого всего запускается при той же java7. Может это подпись как-то игнорируется у меня? Но почему? Какая разница, запускаю я апплет с сайта или из моего HTML?

Comment: А куда мне надо положить этот исправленный файл java.policy в проект апплета? Куда именно?

Comment: Вдруг само собой заработало. Вроде ничего не сделала. Теперь еще чуток изменила и получаю, что приложение заблокировано. Напишу новый вариант в вопрос, а то здесь нечитаемо получается.

Comment: Я сильно не смогу помочь в вопросе подписывания апплетов. Попробуйте свериться, все ли у вас правильно по этой статье: https://habrahabr.ru/post/204984/

Comment: Апплет подписан нормально, я же говорю, что он уже работает на сайте. Просто раньше сайт был на java, а теперь переделывается под nodejs, поэтому надо страницу перевести на javascript.