# Настройки безопасности блокируют подписанный апплет запущеный через Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, applet

Имеется подписанный апплет. Запускается таким образом через HTML и работает:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Applet-Test</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1> Hi html works </h1>
    <applet code="Applet.class" archive="applet.jar" width=320 height=320>
    <param name="locale" value="de"/>
    </applet>
</body>

</html>
```

Теперь пробую сделать то же самое через javascript с использованием jnlp:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
    <information>
        <title>OTC-Applet</title>
        <vendor>BBraun</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.7+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="applet.jar" main="true" />

    </resources>
    <applet-desc 
         name="Applet"
         main-class="Applet" 
         width="1"
         height="1">
         <param name="locale" value="de"/>
    </applet-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

И сам скрипт внутри HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>OTC-Applet Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <script language="javascript">
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>A browser with JavaScript enabled is required for this page to operate properly.</noscript>
    <!-- script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script -->
    <script src="otc.js"></script>
    <script>
        <!-- applet id can be used to get a reference to the applet object -->
        var attributes = { id:'applet', code:'Applet', width:400, height:300} ;
        var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'applet.jnlp', locale: 'de'} ;
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
    </script>


    <h1>OTC Applet</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

В таком варианте блокируется настройками безопаcности java. Что не так здесь? В чем отличие от первого варианта?
Версия Java 1.7.0_67.

Comment: В каких браузерах первое работает, а второе нет?

Comment: Укажите больше информации: названия и версии браузеров. В современных версиях браузеров (Chrome и его клоны, Firefox и его клоны), java аплеты считаются устаревшей и небезопасной технологией и по умолчанию блокируются так, что иногда не помогает даже корректная подпись. А учитывая общую тенденцию, пожалуй имеет смысл обновить технологию (перейти от аплетов в браузерах например на сайт на Bootstrap + Angular или аналоги и backend на Java/Microservices с обменом данными по REST). Конечно, это потребует изучения нового материала.

Answer (score 1):

Для запуска, апплеты должны быть подписанными. Есть тестовые и безплатные сертификаты, но для использования на сайте следует купить сертификат, например, verysign (разные есть, по разным ценам).

Вот пример, как подписать апплет: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/rsa_signing.html

И еще ссылки, может поможет в трудности:

https://habrahabr.ru/post/201210/

http://www.codejava.net/java-se/applet/how-to-sign-a-java-applet?showall=1

https://habrahabr.ru/post/204984/

Answer (score 0):

*Из комментария пользователя [@lospejos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204287/lospejos):*

В современных версиях браузеров (Chrome, Firefox и их клоны) JAVA апплеты считаются устаревшей и небезопасной технологией и по умолчанию блокируются, так что иногда не помогает даже корректная подпись.

А учитывая общую тенденцию, пожалуй имеет смысл обновить технологию (перейти от апплетов в браузерах на Bootstrap + Angular (или аналоги) и backend на Java/Microservices с обменом данными по REST). Конечно, это потребует изучения нового материала.

Answer (score 0):

В современных версиях браузеров (Chrome, Firefox и их клоны) JAVA апплеты считаются устаревшей и небезопасной технологией и по умолчанию блокируются

Для сдачи лабораторных работ в универе виртуальный сервер поместил в исключение. Это можно сделать так:
панель управления -> Java -> вкладка security

 
Edit Site List... (кнопка справа внизу)