# Как правильно создать манифест для апплета для запуска из javascript

Tags: javascript, java, applet

Имеется старый апплет, манифест создается с помощью maven. Но что конкретно должно быть в манифесте? Вот это я туда добавила, но не помогло:

```
Permissions: all-permissions 
Codebase: * 
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: * 
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
```

Чего там еще не хватает? Стоит java 1.7.0_67.
Вот такая ошибка :

```
ava.lang.SecurityException: JAR manifest requested to run in all-permissons only: file:/C:/TestToApplet/Applet.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.isPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Код на HTML полностью описан в вопросе [Настройки безопасности блокируют подписанный апплет запущеный через Javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510487/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-javascript)

Может проблема не в манифесте, а в jnlp? Он тоже описан в вопросе по ссылке выше.